# How I can fetch last two full years and current year records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, msbi

I have following expression in my `where` clause:

```
DA.Access_Date >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())
```

But it returns data till '2015-02-17' i.e. current year minus two.

I want data of two full years and current year

e.g. 2015-01-01 to till date. Any inputs on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Here `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate())` will give start month of the year

```
DA.Access_Date >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,0,GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the year.

Try

```
YEAR(DA.Access_Date) >= (YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be like below.  `DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE())-2,0)` this will returns first day of `2015` year.

```
DA.Access_Date >=  DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE())-2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **YEAR** scalar function

```
WHERE
YEAR(DA.Access_Date) in (YEAR(GETDATE()),YEAR(GETDATE())-1,YEAR(GETDATE())-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in where condition.
Year(DA.Access_Date) >= Year(getdate()) - 2